# SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range:

Tags: mysql, yii, yii2

> Database Exception – yii\db\Exception SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value
>   out of range: 167 Out of range value for column 'id_Permohonan' at row
>   1 The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `permohonan` (`No_Rujukan`,
>   `id_Bulan`, `bulan_Tahun`, `id_Tahun`, `nama_Pesakit`, `no_IC_Baru`,
>   `no_IC_Lama`, `id_jenis_Pemohon`, `siapa`, `id_Alamat`, `id_Bayaran`,
>   `no_Resit_1`, `no_Resit_2`, `tarikh_Resit_1`, `tarikh_Resit_2`,
>   `jumlah_Bayaran_RM`, `status_Laporan_Bermasalah`, `tarikh_Mohon`,
>   `tarikh_Terima`, `tarikh_Kesan`, `tarikh_Hantar_Draf`, `id_Jabatan`,
>   `id_Doktor`, `tarikh_Terima_Draf`, `tarikh_Taip`,
>   `tarikh_Hantar_Tandatangan`, `tarikh_Tandatangan`,
>   `tarikh_Notis_Siap`, `tarikh_Beri`, `bulan_Laporan_Siap`, `btlp`,
>   `id_jenis_Laporan`, `memo`) VALUES ('67372019', 11, '11/2019', 6,
>   'MURNI MANSOR', '790712075748', '', 13, 'SELF', NULL, '1', '', '',
>   NULL, NULL, '40.00', '', '2019-11-12', '2019-11-12', NULL, NULL, 4,
>   259, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '', '', 1, '') Error Info:
>   Array

Comment: seems this is an autoincrement column `id_Permohonan`, which reached the maximum int value

Comment: show your table structure